# Nesting multiple VMs with nested DIVs

Tags: knockout.js

I am experiencing that the nested div wont bind with the VM. Any ideas?I am trying the following and it breaks any ideas?

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2">

   </div>
</div>
```

If I try this is works fine:

```
<div id="div1">
</div>

<div id="div2">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('div1'));
ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById('div2'));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you bind `div1` it will bind everything including what is in `div2`.  When you bind `div2` it will bind the elements again.  This is not a good situation, as elements will have multiple event handlers attached to them.  Otherwise, one of the applyBindings will likely error out as the elements are not expecting to bind against a different view model.

The article here lays out a way to protect the inner element from being bound by the outer call: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

The other option is to use a single view model like:

```
var viewModel = {
  vm1: vm1,
  vm2: vm2
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then, bind like:

```
<div id="div1" data-bind="with: vm1">
   <div id="div2" data-bind="with: $root.vm2">

   </div>
</div>
```