# Knockout multiple bindings on nested dom elements

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

I've managed to get myself into a bit of trouble with a project I'm working on.

Originally the site has one page on it that uses Knockout, with the other pages using jQuery. Due to some problems with the Foundation modal placing itself in the root of the body element, I ended up applying the bindings for the viewmodel for this page to the body element.

Fast forward 4 months, and without foreseeing the trouble I'm in now, I went and rebuilt our shopping basket in Knockout. The shopping basket is visible on every page and is included using a ZF2 partial.

Going back to the page I worked on 4 months ago, it is completely broken with the error message in console saying:

```
Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
```

Here's some code to show my layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body> // 4 month old SPA bound here
        <nav>
            <div id='shopping-basket'> // Shopping basket bound here
                ...
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id='my-app'>
           ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var MyAppViewModel = function() {
   // logic
};

var ShoppingBasketViewModel = function() {
    //logic
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyAppViewModel(), document.body);
ko.applyBindings(new ShoppingBasketViewModel(), document.getElementById('shopping-basket');
```

If I had the time I could go back and rework the original application to sit within it's own div container that would site side by side with the basket, but unfortunately this isn't an option.

The other option is to discard the last bit of work I did on the shopping basket and replace it with jQuery, but this would mean losing a weeks worth of work.

Is there anyway when I'm applying the bindings that I could have both viewmodels working side by side, while being nested in the Dom, and remaining independent of each other?

Comment: please provide knockoutjs code

Comment: yes you can use `ko.applyBinings` second parameter as your div `ID` which resolves the issue . i hope `shopping-basket` & `my-app` are 2 divs right ?

Comment: Sorry, added javascript in to highlight point. Problem is that moving the original SPA into a separate container breaks the application and is not possible, meaning, if possible, both applications need to stay in the container's they're in now.

Comment: oops if you are applying on body and internal div then errr !! problem , no fix as far i know .

Comment: Do I understand right, that your application is only in one page (or in a few pages), whereas the basket is preset in all pages on the site (and the number of all pages is considerably higher than the number of pages with your app)?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek This is correct yes

Comment: @TomHalley Well, the cleanest way would be to overwrite your app to work within its own container. If this is not possible, then you must make the basket a property of your app, and fix the basket initialization, so if on a page with your app, it will become a part of your app, instead of binding itself directly. And you also have to adjust the pages with your app, using the [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) for the `shoping-basket` div. Anyway, I am not sure it would be less work than making your app work in an independent div.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Would it be possible to use ko.cleanNode on part of a bound bit of the dom, just to clean that part of the tree, and then rebind it?

Comment: @TomHalley I've never used that, sorry.

Comment: You could use jQuery to remove `shopping-basket` from the DOM before applying bindings to the body, then re-insert it and apply bindings to it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270259/nesting-multiple-vms-with-nested-divs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had some similar problem. I needed to applybinding to specific nested elements and start with a bind on the document first. Same problem. My solution was to add some ignore element part and than bind the specific element manually.

1) Add a custom binding so you can skip binding on the specific shopping basket:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
         return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;
```

2) Add the custom binding in your html (surround your shopping basket):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
</head>
<body> // 4 month old SPA bound here
    <nav>
        <!--  ko stopBinding: true -->
        <div id='shopping-basket'> // Shopping basket bound here
            ...
        </div>
        <!--  /ko -->
    </nav>
    <div id='my-app'>
       ...
    </div>
</body>
```

3) Apply your bindings as you already do:

```
ko.applyBindings(new MyAppViewModel(), document.body);
ko.applyBindings(new ShoppingBasketViewModel(), document.getElementById('shopping-basket');
```

4) The first bind will skip the shopping-basket because of your custom binding handler and your second bind will explicitly bind the shopping-basket.

I haven't tested the code above on your specific example, but it should point you into the correct direction.

Comment: Words cannot express my gratitude for this, can confirm it worked and saved me one hell of a ball ache!